# Why would a pendant light work while the recessed down lights don't?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just moved into a new house.
In the dressing room there is a pendant light and 8 recessed down lights, all controlled by a dimmer switch.

The weird thing is when we turn the dimmer on only the pendant light works. How can this be? Does it mean that there's a break in the wiring up there or could there be a simple reason?

Comment: Type of lights would help some, LEDs or something else.  Are the recess lights good/working, not burned out?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another switch somewhere for the recessed lights that you just haven't found yet?

Comment: Do all the lights work when the dimmer is at 100%?   Are the downlights sealed LEDs or do they have bulbs screwed in?

Comment: A loose connection at the pendant light or the first down light in the chain is one possible very simple reason for this to happen. It could be that they were incorrectly wired in series (instead of parallel) and the first down light has quit, taking the rest with it.

Answer (score 1):

How could some lights not work when a dimmer is used? As I read it the pendant always works the down lights do not work when dimmed.

The lights that do not work are electronic of some type, led or cfl not all of these lights will function with a dimmer but some will,

There is nothing wrong with the wiring just the lamps themselves, they are not rated for dimming or you have the wrong type of dimmer.

Answer (score -1):

> I just moved into a new house.

Here are some possible explanations:

- If you bought the house from someone who flipped it: no bulbs in downlights. Or they're not connected, purely for decoration. Or whoever installed the lights didn't finish the job, and they never actually worked.
- If it was previously occupied by tenants: all bulbs are either dead or missing. Whoever sold or rented the property to you just changed the easiest one.
- Non-dimmable bulbs in downlights (unlikely, even non-dimmable bulbs would work with the dimmer set to max if the pendant lights up)
- The bulbs are dimmable but the dimmer is temperamental and doesn't like them (unlikely, since the pendant dims)
- Connection broken at pendant light, so it gets power, but the rest of the lights don't.
- All downlights are 12V or other low voltage, all on the same transformer/driver, which is broken.

Investigation: try to eliminate possible causes.

Check downlights for bulbs, check bulb voltage. If bulb is mains voltage, check bulb works by putting it in a known good socket somewhere else. Test if it is dimmable.

If all bulbs are dead, suspect downlights with improper airflow cooking LED bulbs to death, so I'd suggest to replace with lower power bulbs.

If you don't find any bulbs, but instead some proprietary non-replaceable LED  hardware, and they're all out, or if you find 12V bulbs, suspect a dead transformer somewhere. If it's in the ceiling, you'll have to pull it out from one of the holes the downlights fit in. Which one? Time to make bets! You can wiggle the wires and listen for the transformer scratching on the other side of the drywall to find it.

Test the downlights with known dimmable bulb (or incandescent).

Poke the pendant with a broomstick to check for intermittent contact.

If no success, and the downlights are mains powered, without a transformer in between:

Cut power, pull out the dimmer and one downlight, and check continuity between the live wire from dimmer, and the live wire at the downlight. Then find a neutral somewhere, hopefully at the dimmer, and test continuity with the neutral in the downlight. If there is no continuity, pull out the pendant and investigate, there's probably a broken wire nut into which someone tried to squeeze about 10 wires.